# Site Provisioning should work with both on-premises and Online

Tags: provisioning, remote-provisioning

I'm new to site provisioning concept. Currently I'm looking for some POC's that should create a Site Collection with sub-sites. And it should be work with both Online & On-Premises. I got some samples from GitHub, but its working only on Online version. If someone provide/point-out samples for that, it'd be appreciated..

Thanks,

Arun

Comment: are you looking powershell to provisioning the site collection?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE Nope.. I'm looking for coding perspective..